# LVM tools on raw block copy

Tags: lvm, dd

I have several raw block copies of disks that have both NTFS and Linux partitions. The parition tables generally have both a Windows NTFS partition and a Linux LVM partition. I need to work on all of these partitions to build a supertimeline (log2timeline) but I need a good way to find the ext partitions inside the LVM.

I am not familiar at all with and of the LVM commands, though I have a decent grasp on the terminology. Once I get to the byte offset of the ext partitions, I'll be fine, but I'd rather not scan the disk byte by byte for the partition headers and superblocks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at utility called `kpartx`. It creates device maps from partition tables residing within devices.

**Update:**

I wanted to add that if your disk images are stored as ordinary files (as opposed to LVM volumes) you can use `losetup` to attach the images as devices. Specify the `-r` option if you want to make sure that no changes happen to the original image.

Regarding `kpartx`: it also works with LVM volumes within partitions within LVM volumes etc. You just run `kpartx -a DEV` repeatedly for each enclosing partitioning/volume layer until you reach the point where you have a device mapper device node for the file system which you want to mount.